# Show\hide buttons by macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have several macros in my Excel file. For each there is a button in the spreadsheet (not in a userform).

I know the name of the buttons, but I have not found any method to show\hide these buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ActiveX Control use

```
CommandButton1.Visible = False
```

For Form Control use

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Visible = False
```

**In action**

[image]